# Bootstrap data-toggle="collapse" link another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap accordion on a page (we will call it page 2). From a different .aspx page (page 1) I have a list of links that I want to, when clicked on, have the link toggle the accordion so that it opens that accordion drop down once page 2 loads. However I've noticed that the data-toggle="collapse" prevents me from making this work, and yet I need that on my list of links to get it working. any other way to code this?

It looks like the data-toggle="collapse" only works if the links are on the same page. How would I get it to work if it was on a different page?

```js
var anchor = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
$(".collapse").collapse('hide');
$("#" + anchor).collapse('show');
```

```html
<!--BEGIN On page 1-->

<ul>
<li><a href="#collapseOne" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse">Test 1</a></li>
</ul>
<!--END On page 1-->

<!--BEGIN On page 2-->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a id="group-1" class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <i class="more-less glyphicon"></i>
       Group 1
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
    sdfsdffsdfsdfsdf
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

<!--END On page 2-->
```